# 残り一分を切る meaning

Tags: meaning, sentence

> 試合時間が**残り一分を切った**ところで、ゴールを決められて負けてしまった。

I'm not sure about 残り一分を切った. I tried gathering some information and found that 残り一分 = 1 minute left.  But I haven't seen 切る used in this context before, so I searched the meaning it said "to do (something) in less or within a certain time"

So, I translated it as "When the competition time is less than 1 minute, the result has been set that we lost."

I'm not sure but I think that the situation is that the match isn't actually over yet because there's still less than 1 minute left, but the referee (or someone) assumed that we lost already. Am I correct?

BTW: I'm not an English speaker if you can answer in simple language I would be really grateful. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Type 「を切ったところ」 into ALC and surprise, surprise https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%e3%82%92%e5%88%87%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f%e3%81%a8%e3%81%93%e3%82%8d

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to a dictionary 広辞苑:

切る: ➋ 物事を限定する。

3.**（ある数量を）下回る。割る。**「千円を少し―・った値をつける」「10秒を―・る」

So one of the meanings of 切る is "Number or quantity goes down below a certain point".

So 試合時間が残り一分を切ったところで is just talking about WHEN. At the point that there was only one minute left before the game ended.

ゴールを決められて負けてしまった → we conceded a goal, then we lost the game.

Of course it doesn't mean that the game was ended when the goal was made, but the time was run out and they lost.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I got a little question .ゴールを決められて負けてしまった  <- It’s られる form so I think the actual condition is that “ゴールを決められて -> The result was set (by referee or someone/something like our sense). 負けてしまった　-> After that we lost the game  (because the time ran out) Is my opinion correct ?

Comment: @Kyuu Referees are not relevant. [ゴールを決める](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%e3%82%b4%e3%83%bc%e3%83%ab%e3%82%92%e6%b1%ba%e3%82%81%e3%82%8b&ref=sa) is a set phrase "to get a goal", and this られる is so-called a "suffering passive".

Answer (score 4):

> 試合時間が残り一分を切ったところで、ゴールを決められて負けてしまった。

If you cut an object, you usually have some fractions from the whole of the object. i.e. the rest which has not been taken away from the object.

This time, probably you are talking about a football game, you have already taken away(i.e. spent) 44 minutes and the rest is one minute less.

This is the same as ratio. You are focusing on the rest which has not been take away from the whole. For example, describing less than 3/10 of something, it says 「三割を切る」.

---

I think it's pretty much the same as "a measure word" when you cut something and get the slice of it.

> 助数詞。１ 切ったものを数えるのに用いる。「たくあん一切れ」「ようかん二切れ」

*One slice of Takuan pickle. Two slices of Yokan cake.*

You may wonder this kind of expression : "use something up". This one explains something has already been running out. So, it's confusing a little bit.

> ７ （「ぎれ」の形で）名詞の下に付き、そのものを使い切っている意を表す。「期限切れ」「在庫切れ」

*"Time is up", "Running out of the stock."*

Comment: Thank you sir ! I'll phrase it based on my understanding from your explain. Nounを切る gives information about Noun(things) that has not been taken away from the whole. And 切れ (ぎれ) has 2 different meanings depending on contexts -> 1st meaning is to indicate count of something like たくあん一切れ = 1 slice of Takuan as you mentioned. 2nd meaning is suffix "use something up" "run out of something". BTW : 名詞の下 means "after a noun" right ? I have never seen it before but I think it means that. Thank you very much for your deep information.

Comment: @Kyuu you're welcome. Yes, "Noun + 切れ" means running out of "noun" without any numbers (1, 2, 3...).  i.e We do not have any number between "noun" + "切れ". Anyway I think @ lingodeerapp's explanation satisfy you.